# How to say 'LOL' in russian?

Tags: перевод

How do I say 'LOL' in russian?

Comment: Tons of similar abbreviations like OMG, LOL, IMHO, ROFL are literated into ОМГ, ЛОЛ, ИМХО, РОФЛ etc. - they sound the same way. But there are also some abbreviations originated in russian-speaking environment: УГ - унылое говно (sad shit), ХЗ - хрен знает (who knows), ЛС - личное сообщение (private message - PM). Also example is гггг - similar to Spanish jjjjj - meaning "hahahaha" in English.

But LOL would be just ЛОЛ.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The most obvious translation is just "лол".

Also, there are some malformed options: "лал", "лел", "лiл", but they are not common, and I would not give advice to use them

There exist a good analogue - "ржунимагу" (I can't stop laughing)

You can find other analogues there: https://lurkmore.to/LOL

Comment: @DK I can't remember when I've seen 'ржунимагу' last time)

Comment: There is a less expressive "гыгыгы" and "ггг", and ported from korean "кекеке" (usually when someone was pwned)

Comment: While all answers are correct I must say that all of them are basically not used anymore. I am active user of Russian-language internet and I probably haven't seen "ржунимагу", "пацталом" and others for more than 5 years, these are pretty much dead expression and you can sound awkward if you start using them in daily speech(chatting) in 2016. Just use "лол" or regular "ахахаха"(which is simply "ahahaha")

Comment: You forgot about `лулзы` :) And you can say `ржунимагу` in your daily life, no problem :)

Answer (score 10):

• The most adequate Russian analog of 'LOL' is *ржунимагý* which is the phonetic spelling of *ржу, не могу*, '[I'm] nickering (literary 'neighing'), cannot [stop]'.

• Another one is *пацталóм* (= *под столом*), '[laughing having fallen] under the table'.

• One more variant is *бгг!* which is a contracted way of writing *бу-га-гá!*, onomatopoeia that imitates laughing out loud.

Here is [an article](http://lurkmore.to/LOL) about 'LOL' on Lurkmore, a Russian Internet memes wiki.

Answer (score 2):

you can say anything with word ржу (ржать, ржачный, угараю, угарать, угар, угарный), adding necessary definitions on a thing you are laughing about.

"Вот это угар" - this is for real (LOL)

"Угараю (не могу)" - cracking, can't help myself

"Оборжаться" - yeah, LOL

"Ржачный прикол" ~ that's awesome (gag, prank), this (gag, prank is) awesome

and some other, you can catch them in chat

Comment: Вот это угар! Никто так не пишет...